# What criteria is used to transfer daily data from Firebase Crashlytics to Big-Query

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, crashlytics

When Firebase Crashlytics is linked to Bigquery, daily Firebase Crashlytics data is pushed to Biquery,

I want to know how to only select this daily crash data from big-query?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Crashlytics data is exported to BigQuery using the following [schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9036484?hl=en) that contains a field named "event_timestamp", which indicates when an event occurred. The Firebase documentation includes [Crashlytics queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export#examples_of_crashlytics_queries) for querying data in BigQuery, one of these sample queries describes how to query the number of crashes by day for the past month:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT event_id) AS number_of_crashes,
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F", event_timestamp) AS date_of_crashes
FROM
 `projectId.firebase_crashlytics.package_name_ANDROID`
GROUP BY
  date_of_crashes
ORDER BY
  date_of_crashes DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

Taking the above query as base, you would be able to query the number of crashes in a specific day, e.g., the following query will query the crashes on May 5th, 2019:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT event_id) AS number_of_crashes,
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F", event_timestamp) AS date_of_crashes
FROM
 `projectId.firebase_crashlytics.package_name_ANDROID`
WHERE
  event_timestamp = TIMESTAMP('2019-05-05')
```